# Summation of key values during dictionaries merge in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I got these 3 dictionaries:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

e = {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1}

f = {'t': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}
```

I made a new dict:

```
new_dict = {}
```

and then I used:

```
new_dict.update(d)
new_dict.update(e)
new_dict.update(f)
```

and I got :

```
new_dict = {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1, 't': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}
```

but I want to get :

```
{'x': 3, 'y': 5, 'z': 4, 't': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}
```

In other words, I don't want each key and value to override it's previous one - I want to sum the values of each key. how do I do that?

Comment: Use a `collections.Counter` or implement the addition explicitly, update will just replace any existing keys.

Comment: Check if my answer helped you @ temp323232 !

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
e = {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1}
f = {'t': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}

new_dict = Counter(d) + Counter(e) + Counter(f)
print(new_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'y': 5, 'z': 4, 'n': 3, 'x': 3, 'q': 2, 't': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
e = {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1}
f = {'t': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}

l = [d,e,f]

new_dict = Counter()
for d in l:
    new_dict.update(d)
```

and you get:

```
Counter({'x': 3, 'y': 5, 'z': 4, 't': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over each dictionary and add up the values of same keys, instead of creating 3 `Collections.Counter` instances

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
e = {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1}
f = {'t': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}

dct = {}
#Iterate over every dict
for l in [d, e, f]:
    #Add up values for the same key
    for k,v in l.items():
        if k in dct:
            dct[k] += v
        else:
            dct[k] = v

print(dct)
#{'x': 3, 'y': 5, 'z': 4, 't': 1, 'q': 2, 'n': 3}
```